# How to judge whether these series of numbers have converged

Tags: sequences-and-series

**Note:** The following questions are from the 4th question of the [2008 Chinese Graduate Mathematical Entrance Examination](https://kaoyan.eol.cn/shiti/shuxue/201605/t20160516_1398298_1.shtml) (first set):

Let f (x) be monotonically bounded in $(-\infty,+\infty)$ and $\left\{x_{n}\right\}$ is a sequence of numbers, which of the following propositions is true:

$$
\begin{array}{c}
&(A)& \text{ If } \left\{x_{n}\right\} \text{converges, then} \left\{f\left(x_{n}\right)\right\} \text{converges.}\\
&(B)& \text{ If }  \left\{x_{n}\right\} \text{is monotonic, then} \left\{f\left(x_{n}\right)\right\} \text{converges.}\\
&(C)& \text{ If }  \left\{f\left(x_{n}\right)\right\} \text{converges, then} \left\{x_{n}\right\} \text{converges.}\\
&(D)& \text{ If } \left\{f\left(x_{n}\right)\right\} \text{is monotonic, then} \left\{x_{n}\right\} \text{converges.}
\end{array}$$

I already know that the answer is `B`(monotone bounded sequence must converge), but I want to know why the other three items are incorrect, and if possible, give a counterexample or give a strict mathematical proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Counterexample for $A$ : let $f(x)=-1$ if $x \leq 0$ and $f(x)=1$ if $x > 0$. For $x_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$, $(x_n)$ converges but $f(x_n) = (-1)^n$ does not converges.

Counterexample for $C$ and $D$ : let $f(x)=0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. For $x_n = n$, $(f(x_n))$ converges and is monotonic but $(x_n)$ does not converge.